# upgrade package version in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, jna

I am on ubuntu 14.04.3. When I try to install libjna-java using 
sudo apt-get install libjna-java
it installs 3.2.7-4 version of jna. But I actually need 3.3.0 version of jna. Is there anyway I can install 3.3.0 jna ?